# How to execute multiple global commands in Vim sequentially? (Error: "Cannot do :global recursive")

Tags: vim, global, ex

I want to sort the paragraphs in my text according to their initials with the following global command:

```
g/_p/,/^$/mo$
```

This works alone. But when I use several global commands at once, then an error occurs:

```
g/_p/,/^$/mo$|g/_w/,/^$/mo$
```

This gives the following error:

```
Cannot do :global recursive
```

How can I run these commands sequentially at once?

Comment: ([Here](https://superuser.com/a/366354/21887) are a few lines of vimscript that sort all paragraphs. But they recognize the paragraphs by indentation, not empty lines. But surely one could adapt it to distinguish paragraphs by empty lines.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
:exe 'g/_p/,/^$/mo$' | g/_w/,/^$/mo$
```

To append more `global` commands, just keep wrapping them in `execute`:

```
:execute 'g/aaa/s//bbb/g ' | execute 'g/ccc/s/ddd//g' | execute 'g/eee/s/fff/ggg/g' | g/^cake/s/$/ is a lie/g
```

The reason for the error is in `:help`[`:bar`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:bar):

> **`*:bar* *:\bar*`**      `|` can be used to separate commands, so you can give multiple commands in one line.  If you want to use `|` in an
>   argument, precede it with `\`.
>
> These commands see the `|` as their argument, and can therefore not be
>   followed by another Vim command:
>
> - (.. list of commands ..)
> - `:global`
> - (.. list of commands ..)
>
> Note that this is confusing (inherited from Vi): With `:g` the `|` is
>   included in the command, with `:s` it is not.
>
> To be able to use another command anyway, use the [`:execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute)
>   command.

This also answers why the below chain would work without any issues:

```
%s/htm/html/c | %s/JPEG/jpg/c | %s/GIF/gif/c
```

Comment: In this case it is not necessary to wrap both `:global` commands in `:execute`, it is enough to wrap only the first one: `:exe'g/_p/,/^$/mo$'|g/_w/,/^$/mo$`.

Comment: @ib.: I incorporated your suggestion. Nice one, thanks! I especially like the fact, that you even saved the space between `:exe` and its parameter `'…`. xD