# Conditional action in a macro

Tags: vim, buffer, vim-macros

In a VIM macro, how are the conditional actions handled?

```
 if condition is true
       do this
 else
       do something else
```

### Basic example

File content:

```
_
abcdefg
```

The macro will do:

```
G^
if letter is one of the following letters: a e i o u
   gg$i0<ESC>
else
   gg$i1<ESC>
Gx
```

Repeated 7 times the buffer will be:

```
_0111011
```

So, how can I verify if a condition is true and then run an action?

Comment: @romainl Some research on Internet, but actually, I have no idea how this can be done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As there's no "conditional" command in Vim, this cannot strictly be done with a macro. You can only use the fact that when a command in a macro beeps, the macro replay is aborted. Recursive macros use this fact to stop the iteration (e.g. when the `j` command cannot move to a following line at the end of the buffer).

On the other hand, conditional logic is very easy in Vimscript, and a macro can `:call` any Vimscript function easily.

Your example could be formulated like this:

```
function! Macro()
    " Get current letter.
    normal! yl
    if @" =~# '[aeiou]'
        execute "normal! gg$i0\<ESC>"
    else
        execute "normal! gg$i1\<ESC>"
    endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to adopt a more functional (as opposed to imperative) approach e.g. this particular task (and [many others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765347)) can be done with a substitution:

```
G:s/\v([aeiou])|./\=strlen(submatch(1)) ? 1 : 0/g<CR>gggJ
```

i.e.:

```
G  " go to the first non-blank character on the last line

" replace each vowel with 1 and everything else with 0
:s/\v([aeiou])|./\=strlen(submatch(1)) ? 1 : 0/g<CR>

gg " go to the first line
gJ " and append the line below
```

Depending on the task, you might find that plugins (such as [abolish.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish)) package the logic in a more convenient way than dropping to vimscript.

Another approach is to use `:global` as described [here](http://viming.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/conditionally-applying-macro-recordings.html), again moving any additional logic into the command(s) where convenient/necessary. If the text to process isn't already in the right format for `:g` (which is line-based), it can be split into lines, operated on with `:g`, and then reassembled/restored.

You can also bundle together a sequence of non-overlapping commands with `|` (`:help :bar`) to approximate an `if/else` chain e.g. to convert:

```
DMY: 09/10/2011 to 10/11/2012
DMY: 13/12/2011
MDY: 10/09/2011 to 11/10/2012
MDY: 12/13/2011
```

to:

```
DMY: 2011-10-09 to 2012-11-10
DMY: 2011-12-13
MDY: 2011-10-09 to 2012-11-10
MDY: 2011-12-13
```

formatted for clarity (for the `:execute` usage see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750697/multiple-global-commands-in-vim-gives-error-cannot-do-global-recursive)):

```
:exe 'g/^DMY:/s/\v(\d\d)\D(\d\d)\D(\d{4})/\3-\2-\1/g' |
      g/^MDY:/s/\v(\d\d)\D(\d\d)\D(\d{4})/\3-\1-\2/g
```